# Does DepenencyProperty AddOwner include FrameworkPropertyMetadata?

Tags: c#, wpf

When a `DependencyProperty` that has `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault` set is reused in a different control via `AddOwner(typeof(NewOwner))` does this reuse include the two way binding behavior or should I set it like `AddOwner(typeof(NewOwner, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault))`.

I would expect it does but somehow it looks like it doesn't. When you check the metadata using GetMetadata on the property I can't check it for the added owner.

See this example:

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty = ListBox.SelectedItemProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyControl));
}
```

then inspect using:

```
  var x = ListBox.SelectedItemProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(ListBox)) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
  bool bx = x.BindsTwoWayByDefault;  // true;
  var y = MyControl.SelectedItemProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(MyControl)) as FrameworkPropertyMetadata;
  bool by = y.BindsTwoWayByDefault; // null pointer excpetion
```

Comment: Try [this AddOwner overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.addowner?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_DependencyProperty_AddOwner_System_Type_System_Windows_PropertyMetadata_). Note the Remarks: *The supplied metadata is merged with the property metadata ...*

Comment: @Clemens I guess it only copies the PropertyMetadata part not the FrameworkPropertyMetadata.

Comment: Just tested this, and I can confirm your observation. It is necessary to provide new FrameworkPropertyMetadata with FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, otherwise the property won't bind two-way by default. This seems to be in contradiction to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.addowner?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_DependencyProperty_AddOwner_System_Type_System_Windows_PropertyMetadata_), where they say *any characteristics that were specified in the original base metadata will persist*

Comment: Probably AddOwner without explicitly set FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions just set the default flags value, which does not contain BindsTwoWayByDefault.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597484(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Adds another type as an owner of a dependency property that has already been registered, **providing dependency property metadata for the dependency property as it will exist on the provided owner type**.

Comment: Yes but I cannot inspect it using GetMetadata.

Comment: I guess, it's in owner?

Comment: please check my repo

Comment: This documentation is kind of ambiguous it states that it provides the metadata for the owner. Could also imply that it has different metadata for the new owner. Similar to using register with default metadata.

Comment: Well, `GetMetadata` returns metadata on **existing** type. Since this property is shared, we won't see it in type's metadata.